# QGIS 3.4 ERROR:/bin/sh: 1: gdal_polygonize.py: not found

Tags: gdal, convert, qgis-3

I am working with Xubuntu 18.04 Bionic and QGIS 3.4.

When I try to convert raster to vector (polygonise) with **GDAL command**

```
gdal_polygonize.py /home/tec/Documents/QGISdata/ADN_Avignon_DAB2018b/GeoTif/AviTw1kWdip0deg67a200dB_georef.tif /tmp/processing_edce935fd39d49c4b7e72e38ecf39bdf/c7ed019e0366436c80ac9ebd6e4a97b1/OUTPUT.shp -8 -b 1 -f "ESRI Shapefile" None DN
```

I get this message, **GDAL command output**

```
/bin/sh: 1: gdal_polygonize.py: not found
```

What can I do to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

```
$ sudo apt install python-gdal
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$ sudo apt install python-gdal
```

I use 3.10.3-A Coruña on Linux Mint 18 (i.e. Ubuntu 18 something...)